# Conditional Joins based on values existing

Tags: sql-server-2008

would like some input on the following scenario (using MSSQL08). Say I have a 'User' table containing a list of 'Users', their 'CurrentCode' (2 digit) and for some a 'JobCode' (3 digit). I would like to update the 'CurrentCode' field to a more accurate 3 digit code, so I have created a single column table of these codes called 'NewCode'.

The 'NewCode' field relates directly to the 'JobCode' field, so updating the 'CurrentCode' for the users that have a valid 'JobCode' is easy. However for those that don't have a 'JobCode' (are 'NA') I'm just doing a match of their current 2 digit code to the first 2 digits of a listing in the 'NewCode' table.

I have been able to output this as follows, using 2 joins to instances of the 'NewCode' table ('Confirmed' linked to 'JobCode' if a value exists and 'Matched' linked to 'CurrentCode' if not):

```
+------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+
| User | CurrentCode | JobCode | NewCode - Confirmed | NewCode - Matched |
+------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+
| A    |          11 |     111 |                 111 |                   |
| B    |          12 |      NA |                     |               120 |
| C    |          23 |     232 |                 232 |                   |
| D    |          42 |     423 |                 423 |                   |
| E    |          11 |     112 |                 112 |                   |
| F    |          21 |      NA |                     |               210 |
| G    |          33 |      NA |                     |               330 |
+------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

I'm interested to see how I could combine the 2 joins to the 'NewCode' table such that it would return the codes in the one column depending on there being a match in the 'JobCode' field or not. Eg:

```
+------+-------------+---------+---------+
| User | CurrentCode | JobCode | NewCode |
+------+-------------+---------+---------+
| A    |          11 |     111 |     111 |
| B    |          12 |      NA |     120 |
| C    |          23 |     232 |     232 |
| D    |          42 |     423 |     423 |
| E    |          11 |     112 |     112 |
| F    |          21 |      NA |     210 |
| G    |          33 |      NA |     330 |
+------+-------------+---------+---------+
```

How would I go about creating this conditional join to the one table instance, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional Join is possible, while in your case you can do it in a simple way using `ISNULL()` in your SELECT

```
ISNULL([NewCode - Confirmed], [NewCode - Matched]) AS NewCode
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, that worked. Out of interest though, how would you structure a conditional join to do it as well? Could you use a case? Eg `join NewCode on (case when JobCode not null then` ...

Comment: @David_S53 I think it is a hard way, yes the join condition accepts `case` but you will also need to do the `ISNULL()` in the select

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. Just had me thinking, which is prob why i missed the simpler isnull() answer..